# Удаление нескольких изображений из разных таблиц

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Не могу понять, что не так, помогите. Хотел сделать так, чтоб когда пользователь удаляет каталог, вместе с каталогом удалились все посты, которые содержат этот каталог. 
Вот `php` код:

```
<?php include ("../blocks/bd.php");
if (isset ($_POST['id']))          {$id = $_POST['id']; }
if (isset ($_POST['link']))          {$link = $_POST['link']; }
if (isset ($_POST['TypeRealty']))          {$TypeRealty = $_POST['TypeRealty']; }
            //Если все перемунные существует
          if (isset($id) && isset($link)&& isset($TypeRealty))
          {
              //Извлекаем все миниатюры постов и номера постов
              $resultImg = mysql_query("SELECT mini_img, numberPost FROM $TypeRealty WHERE cat='$id'");

                while ($delMiniImg = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultImg)) // сдесь дает ощибку Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in Z:\home\golden\www\admingold\realty\deleteCat.php on line 11
                    {
                        $resultDelMiniImg = unlink('../../'.$delMiniImg['mini_img']); //Удаляем все миниатюры которые существует где cat='$id'
                      }

                  if ($resultDelMiniImg == 'true' || !file_exists('../../'.$resultDelMiniImg['mini_img'])) //Влюбом случае извлекаем все изображений относящиеся этим постам, которые находится в таблице img с идентификатом numberPost
                    {$numerPost = $delImg['numberPost'];
                        $resultDelImg = mysql_query ("SELECT imgUrl, mini_img FROM img WHERE numberPost='$numerPost'");

                            while ($delImg = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultDelImg)) 
                                {
                                    $resultDelImg = unlink('../../'.$delImg['imgUrl']);
                                    $resultDelImg2 = unlink('../../'.$delImg['mini_img']);
                                }
                                if ($resultDelImg == 'true' && $resultDelImg2 == 'true' 
                                    || !file_exists('../../'.$resultDelImg['imgUrl'])
                                    || !file_exists('../../'.$resultDelImg2['mini_img'])) //После удаления файлов удаляем из БД где numberPost='$numerPost'
                                {$delImgTb = mysql_query ("DELETE FROM img WHERE numberPost='$numerPost'");}

                    }

                if($delImgTb == 'true') 
                    {$delData = mysql_query ("DELETE FROM $TypeRealty WHERE cat='$id'");}
         if ($delData == 'true'){
          $result = mysql_query ("DELETE FROM cat WHERE id='$id'");
          $file="../../images/".$link;
                    $unl = unlink($file);

                if ($result == 'true' && $unl == 'true') { echo "<p>Каталог успешно удален</p>";}
                    else{echo "<p>Каталог не удален</p>";}
              }
          }
          else
          {
          echo "<p>Вы не выбрали каталога для удаления!</p>";
          }

          ?>
```

Comment: выбрось курсы Попова

Comment: ))))) как Вы угадали)))), это только в начале его а остальные мои))

Comment: прямо фабрика быдлокодеров этот ваш попов... 
никогда не пишите ничего подобного. 
а по конкретному примеру удостоверьтесь что переменные `$TypeRealty` и `$id` содержат валидные значения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала правим вот это

```
//Извлекаем все миниатюры постов и номера постов
              $resultImg = mysql_query("SELECT mini_img, numberPost FROM $TypeRealty WHERE cat='$id'");
```

на вот это

```
//Извлекаем все миниатюры постов и номера постов
                  $resultImg = mysql_query("SELECT mini_img, numberPost FROM $TypeRealty WHERE cat='".$id."'");
```

в том же духе правим все запросы